# Take data from Enum to show on UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uipickerview

I am creating a simple View where there is a UIPickerView and I want to display the choices on the PickerView from an enum. I have created an enum of possible drinks

```
enum drink{
  case coffee
  case tea
  case cola
  case water
}
```

I was wondering how it would be possible to display the drinks in an UIPickerView? I am using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.1.. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by `ABakerSmith` you can use the Printable protocol to display the `String` in the `UIPickerView`.

In the end you can have a `ViewController` looking as the following:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 04/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

enum Drink: Int, Printable {
    case Coffee = 0
    case Tea = 1
    case Cola = 2
    case Water = 3
    static var count: Int { return Drink.Water.rawValue + 1 }

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Coffee: return "Coffee"
        case .Tea   : return "Tea"
        case .Cola  : return "Cola"
        case .Water : return "Water"
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDataSource

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Drink.count
}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return Drink(rawValue: row)?.description;
}

// several optional methods:

// func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat

// func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat

// func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString!

// func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView!

// func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
}
```

Comment: For `count`, wouldn't it be better to use a static read-only computed property. With the current approach you'd be able to write `let drink = Drink.count`, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: That is true, `count` could potentially be replaced with the following:

`static var count: Int { return Drink.Water.hashValue + 1 }`

Then you just gotta make sure to update the `Water` reference if you add any more values later.

Answer (score 5):

Apple introduced [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) in Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10+ which makes this cleaner.

> The compiler can automatically provide an implementation of the CaseIterable requirements for any enumeration without associated values or @available attributes on its cases. The synthesized allCases collection provides the cases in order of their declaration.

Example:

```
enum Drink: String, CaseIterable {
    case coffee = "Coffee"
    case tea = "Tea"
    case cola = "Cola"
    case water = "Water"
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Drink.allCases[row].rawValue
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Drink.allCases.count
    }
}
```

You can find a full example using a `UITextField` on [Github](https://github.com/yothenberg/uikit-enum-picker)

Answer (score 4):

Give them a String and call it with rawValue.

```
enum Drink: String {
    case Coffee = "Coffee"
    case Tea = "Tea"
    case Cola = "Cola"
    case Water = "Water"
}

println(Drink.Coffee.rawValue) // Prints "Coffee"
```

As ABakerSmith mentioned in his answer, you can use printable as well. In the next example it's a little different compared to the approach of ABakerSmith's.

```
enum Drink: String, Printable {
    case Coffee = "Coffee"
    case Tea = "Tea"
    case Cola = "Cola"
    case Water = "Water"

    var description: String { return rawValue }
}

println(Drink.Coffee) // Prints "Coffee"
```

As Leonardo Savio Dabus mentioned, a simplified version.

Comment: You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces:

Comment: var description: String {
        return rawValue
    }

Answer (score 1):

I would make `Drink` conform to the `Printable` protocol:

The `Printable` protocol looks like:

```
protocol Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

Therefore, your `Drink` enum would be:

```
enum Drink : Printable {
    case Coffee
    case Tea
    case Cola
    case Water

    var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .Coffee: return "Coffee"
            case .Tea   : return "Tea"
            case .Cola  : return "Cola"
            case .Water : return "Water"
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example of using a `Drink` in a `String`:

```
let myDrink: Drink = .Tea
println("I'm drinking \(myDrink)") // I'm drinking Tea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum like this way;

```
enum drink: String{
    case coffee = "coffee"
    case tea = "tea"
    case cola = "cola"
    case water = "water" 
}
```

You can add uipickerview in this example;

> http://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-in-swift/