# Possible to Make a Generic Enum UIPickerView

Tags: swift, generics, uipickerview

Is it possible to write a generic UIPickerView subclass where you could pass in an arbitrary enum type and have it fill the picker view with all the cases of said enumeration?

Note: This needs to be done generically for an arbitrarily passed in enum type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take data from Enum to show on UIPickerView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025481/take-data-from-enum-to-show-on-uipickerview-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally was able to write a generic enum aware picker view.  Here's what I did.  First I made a PickableEnum protocol, as so:

```
protocol PickableEnum: Hashable {
   static var allValues: [Self] {get}
   var pickerText:   String {get}
}
```

I needed the ability to generically know what all the enumeration cases are.  That's the job of the allValues property, the implementation of which I found online.

https://theswiftdev.com/2017/01/05/18-swift-gist-generic-allvalues-for-enums/)

Here's the code:

```
extension PickableEnum {

   static func cases() -> AnySequence<Self> {
      typealias S = Self
      return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<S> in
         var raw = 0
         return AnyIterator {
            let current : Self = withUnsafePointer(to: &raw) { $0.withMemoryRebound(to: S.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee } }
            guard current.hashValue == raw else { return nil }
            raw += 1
            return current
         }
      }
   }

   static var allValues: [Self] {
      return Array(self.cases())
   }
}
```

The PickableEnum also has a read-only string property called pickerText for getting the text that will appear in the picker interface.

The rest is trivial.  Make your UI class take a generic qualifier of the appropriate type, then configure your UIPickerView accordingly:

```
class EnumPickerView<T:PickableEnum> : UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

   private let enumCases = T.allValues
   private var currentValue: T

   init(frame: CGRect, initialValue: T) {
      currentValue = initialValue
      super.init(frame: frame)
      dataSource = self
      delegate = self
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   var value: T {
      get {
         return currentValue
      }
   }

   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 1
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      return enumCases.count
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
      return enumCases[row].pickerText
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      currentValue = enumCases[row]
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
enum SomeValues: Int {

    static var count: Int { return SomeValues.lastValue.hashValue + 1 }

    case valueA = 0
    case valueB = 1
    case valueC = 2
    case lastValue = 3
    case noValue = 4

    func rawString() -> String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Using the values for your picker:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return SomeValues.count
}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    guard let value = SomeValues(rawValue: component), value != .noValue else { return "Handle however you want" }

    return value.rawString()
}
```